# Prove electric field is continuous at an external point $P$

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, density

I have a continuous charge distribution with density $\rho$.

[image]

Can anyone please tell how shall I prove the electric field is continuous at an external point $P$?

> $\displaystyle \mathbf{E}=\dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_V \rho  \dfrac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3}  dV'$

Comment: Is anyone here?

Comment: Have you considered the differential version of Gauss' law ($\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$)? It means $\mathbf{E}$ is non-continuous only at places where $\rho$ is infinite.

Comment: How? Can you provide (or provide a link) of that theorem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a rigorous proof at hand, but that's where I would start. The thing to prove would then be that a discontinuity in $\mathbf{E}$ must lead to an infinite $\nabla \mathbf{E}$.

Comment: Then four theorems come out of it: (1) discontinuity in $\mathbf{E}$ implies infinite $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}$ (2) infinite $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}$ implies discontinuity (3) continuity in $\mathbf{E}$ implies finite $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}$ (4) finite $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}$ implies continuity in $\mathbf{E}$. Can you give at least a mathematical or "physics" proof of the last one?

Comment: Note that I just need the proof at an external point. I know $\dfrac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3}$ is continuous at all external points. Hence  $\dfrac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3} \rho\ dV'$ is continuous at all external points. Since superposition of infinite continuous functions is a continuous function, $\mathbf{E}$ is continuous at all external points. Is this proof correct?

Comment: "superposition of infinite continuous functions is a continuous function"... Is this statement correct?

Comment: That's not correct in general, since Fourier transforms can create a square wave from an infinite number of continuous sine waves.